# Proof of a closure of S is itself a closed set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

I just wanted to verify if the following proof is a valid strategy to show that the the Closure of a set is closed.

I have used the following result to prove this is true:

1) A point x is in cl S iff every neighbourhood of x intersects S

2) N*(x;epsilon) is the x deleted epsilon neighbourhood of x

**Strategy**: Aim to show that if $x\in clS'$ then $x\in clS$.

**Proof**

Suppose $x\in clS'$, then $\forall\epsilon>0$, $N^{*}(x;\epsilon)\land clS\neq\textrm{Ø}$

then

$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists y\in$ $N^{*}(x;\epsilon)\land clS$

$\Longleftrightarrow$$\exists y\in$ $N^{*}(x;\epsilon)\land(S\lor S')$

$\Longleftrightarrow$$\exists y\in$ $(N^{*}(x;\epsilon)\land S)$
$\lor$$(N^{*}(x;\epsilon)\land S')$

Suppose first that $y\in$ $N^{*}(x;\epsilon)\land S$

then $N^{*}(x;\epsilon)\land S$ $\neq\textrm{Ø}$, so $x\in clS$

Now suppose $y\in$ $N^{*}(x;\epsilon)\land S'$

then $y\in S'$, but if $y\in S',$then $\forall\delta,\exists z$
such that $N^{*}(y;\delta)\land S\neq\textrm{Ø}$

but then z$\in$$N^{*}(y;\delta)\subseteq$$N^{*}(x;\epsilon)$, so
$N^{*}(x;\epsilon)\land S$ $\neq\textrm{Ø}$, so $x\in clS$

**End Proof**

thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by $S'$? In any case, there's a straightforward proof: if $y \not\in cl S$, then $y$ has some open neighborhood that does not intersect $S$. Hence ...

Comment: The usual notation for the closure of $S$ is $\bar S$. And $cl (S)$ is also used, especially when "$S$" is a complicated expression

Comment: Thank you, S' is the set of all accumulation (limit) points of S

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is ok. Here is a pure topological proof without using metric.

Since $\overline{\overline{S}}=\overline{S\cup S'}\supset \overline{S}$, it only needs to prove $\overline{\overline{S}}\subset \overline{S}$.

By definition of closure, $\overline{\overline{S}}$ is the smallest close set containing $\overline{S}$. Since $\overline{S}\subset\overline{S}$, there is $\overline{\overline{S}}\subset \overline{S}$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you use the punctured neighborhoods. I think the proof is essentially correct, but it can be streamlined.

Let $S'$ be the closure of $S$ and suppose $x$ belongs to the closure of $S'$. Let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $x$. By hypothesis, $U\cap S'\ne\emptyset$, so take $y\in U\cap S'$. Since $U$ is open, it is also a neighborhood of $y$ and, since $y$ belongs to the closure of $S$, $U\cap S\ne\emptyset$.

We have proved that every open neighborhood of $x$ intersects $S$ and, therefore, that $x$ belongs to the closure of $S$.

If you want to use neighborhoods of the form $N(z,\varepsilon)$, you can do it as follows:

1. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then $N(x,\varepsilon)\cap S'\ne\emptyset$
2. Let $y\in N(x,\varepsilon)\cap S'$; there exists $\varepsilon'$ such that $N(y,\varepsilon')\subseteq N(x,\varepsilon)$ (just take $\varepsilon'=d(x,y)/2$)
3. Since $y\in S'$, $N(y,\varepsilon')\cap S\ne\emptyset$
4. Therefore $N(x,\varepsilon)\cap S\ne\emptyset$